# i would like to convert these without using lambda expression in the code for java1.7

Tags: java, spring, lambda

```
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return getRoles().stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole().name()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

//i would like to convert these without using lambda expression in the code for java1.7

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the type of `getRoles()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your `getRoles()` returns `List<Role>`, then result will look like this:

```
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleGrantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
for (Role role : getRoles()) {
    simpleGrantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole().name()));
}

return simpleGrantedAuthorities;
```